# Best practice for redundant conditions in if-elif-else statements

Tags: python, coding-style, efficiency, if-statement

What is considered better practice?

Case 1:

```
if n == 0:
    doThis()
elif n < 0:
    doThat()
elif n > 0:
    doSomethingElse()
```

Case 2:

```
if n == 0:
    doThis()
elif n < 0:
    doThat()
else:
    doSomethingElse()
```

The first case is more explicit and (arguably) clearer.

The second case doesn't handle the incorrect case when `n` is not an integer. Pass in a non-integer object (one that implements `__lt__` and `__eq__`) and it returns without throwing error. This isn't expected behavior. If this was written in a statically-typed language, this wouldn't be a problem. But this is Python.

The second case is, however, potentially quicker, because it avoids an extra conditional expression evaluation (i.e., the `n > 0` statement).

Comment: Not a full answer, but the main difference between the two styles are whether you want a _default_ option, or exclusively _specific_ options. So the answer is likely "it depends".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710333/is-there-a-way-to-match-inequalities-in-python-%E2%89%A5-3-10

Comment: @NotThatGuy Not necessarily a code smell. Design-wise, if `n`'s operations are vectorized, `n == 0`, `n < 0`, `n > 0` may all return empty collections, which might be reasonably considered falsy.

Comment: The first case also returns without an error if none of the conditions are true. It just never calls any of the doXXX. The second version lumps "none true" in with "n > 0". Either could be wrong.

Comment: @NotThatGuy until you run into https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_relation or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/partial_ordering

Comment: (1) The first is *less* explicit since it doesn't explicitly state that these branches are exhaustive; you have to infer that from the conditions, whereas `else` makes the exhaustiveness explicit. (2) The case where `n` is a user-defined type implementing `__lt__` is not really an issue, since in that case either the comparison still does make sense for that type, or otherwise the custom implementation of `__lt__` should raise `TypeError` or return `NotImplemented` (causing a `TypeError`).

Comment: You should omit the final `elif`. When I read your code and I see a chain of else-ifs and no final catch-all else, I get the feeling that that you purposefully wanted to skip the entire thing sometimes, and that's clearly misleading.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Do you consider floating point variables "code smell"? Because a floating point value of `NaN` would behave exactly like that. (any comparison with a NaN value returns false. Including `NaN == NaN`).

Comment: "(one that implements `__lt__` and `__eq__`) and it returns without throwing error. This isn't expected behavior." - As far as the if-statement and the comparison operators are concerned, that *is* the expected behavior. The restriction to integers is imposed by *you*, and is not the job of the if statement or the comparison operators to enforce it - it's *your* job. Either add the code that does the appropriate type checks, build the system so you can assume integers, or rethink the restriction and allow non-integers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Short answer

I would argue that there is no singular correct answer to this question.

It depends on what you want to have happen when one of the above cases changes. Are you assuming that the last case catches everything that's left? While the previous question may seem an obvious rephrasing from asking if you want it to work the way an `else` case works, sometimes the simplest questions are the ones that get you to the rightest answers.

### Much longer answer

When you ask what is better, "better" here includes checking which is best logically, readably, speedily, and maintanably.

**Logically**, they're equivalent.
*Edit: I was not aware of `NaN` in Python being an option here. The two options are only logically equivalent if they both cover every possible value, but `NaN` is not being covered for here. However, if you could somehow guarantee that `NaN` would not be a possible value here (e.g. this already being established in an earlier part of the code), then they would be logically equivalent.*

**Readably**, the `elif` option is the most informative as it describes the case. However, I could make the point that a code comment would achieve the same purpose. So while the `elif` option *slightly* favors readability, if we find a reason to favor the `else` option for other reasons, we can mitigate this by adding a comment to the `else` option.

**Speedily**, the `else` variant is better due to having one less redundant consideration. That being said, what I just said only applies **if** this last condition fully covers every possible scenario that is left (i.e. after all the other conditions have turned up false already), and **if** you care about this level of performance. Generally speaking there is not such a performance constraint, and the question being asked here is more one of readability and maintenance (as so many good practice questions are).

So far, `elif` favors readability (but only by a tiny margin) and `else` favors performance (but only in relatively rare scenarios). I'm going to call this mostly a tie.

**Maintainably**, this is where the context matters. You used an example of a complete set (all integer numbers), and you picked cases that together form the whole set. There is no reasonable expectation that new numbers will be invented. Therefore, the last condition of the `elif` option is truly redundant.

However, you've unknowingly cherrypicked an example that introduces a constraint that doesn't always apply. I suspect you were asking a much broader question, so I'm going to use a different example that addresses a much broader set of use cases.

Let's say we have a company with five employees. Two of the staff are managers. The other three are developers. In this company, managers earn $150k, developers earn $100k, and no one has (or will ever have) personally negotiated salaries.

You can now rephrase your question to this example, which asks whether this ...

```
if(employee.Role == "Manager")
    salary = 150000;
else
    salary = 100000;
```

... or this ...

```
if(employee.Role == "Manager")
    salary = 150000;
else if(employee.Role == "Developer")
    salary = 100000;
```

... is better. You may have already noticed what's different about this example compared to yours: this is not a complete dataset. Over time, it's possible that you might hire an accountant. What should their salary be?

I very intentionally kept the salary rules vague, leaving it unspoken how the rule is designed. There are two main possibilities here:

1. Everyone earns the same salary, but managers get a $50k bonus.
2. Each role has a specifically agreed upon salary.

In the first case, an accountant inherently earns the same as a developer. Therefore, the `else` case is the better option, because it accurately separates the managers from "everyone else" (notice the "else" there).

In the second case an accountant's salary and a developer's salary have no relation to each other, and therefore the logic should not group them together. Therefore, the `elif` case is the better options, because it ensures that the salary amounts are correctly tied to the role that they belong to.

The question here is what happens when you forget to update this logic. With the `else` option, accountants will immediately earn the same as developers, which matches the first case listed here. With the `elif` option, accountants will not be given a salary until someone has explicitly decided what it should be, which matches the second case listed here.

---

### **Conclusion**

Because I can't resist the opportunity here:

```
if(performance_matters_a_lot)
    return "else";
else if(current_logic_represents_final_and_complete_set)
    return "else";
else
    return "elif";
```

Yes, I did doublecheck that using `else` was consistent with the information in this answer.

Comment: I love the points addressed here. But this misses the (IMO) biggest point by declaring "Logically, they're equivalent".  You can't correctly select an if-style without recognizing the logical impact they have when your assumptions about values are (inevitably) incorrect. Oscar's answer illustrates this quite well. Combined, your answers cover it all wonderfully

Comment: @Indigenuity: I'm no Python expert and wasn't aware there was a non-numerical value possible here. If this were a C# integer, OP's cases would completely cover the possible values and then the two presented options would be logically equivalent. But you're right about this because it's Python, so I'm adding an asterisk to this part of my answer.

Comment: I'd put an `else: throw Exception('unhandled value')` if doing an elif chain. It might seem redundant but, using your salary example, the code you provided will be logically flawed and potentially difficult to notice when it doesn't explode when accountants are added to the system.

Comment: @Shadow: How the code should behave when a new option is introduced is subjective/contextual and there's no one correct answer to cover all use cases. Exceptions are not necessarily the correct behavior and I intentionally stay away from that kind of blanket advice in this answer.

Comment: @Flater Doing nothing maybe not correct behaviour either, so an exception is the better option because the error then doesn't slip by silently.  Even if doing nothing would be the correct behaviour this should be said explicitly in the code.

Comment: @Shadow You're missing the key point being made here. By the very definition of providing an example (to talk about something else) I needed to use _one_ of the _many possible_ ways to respond to cases that aren't covered. **I never claimed that the approach my example takes is the _only_ correct way**. The comments here boil down to either "well it depends" which mirrors exactly what the first paragraph of my answer points out, or "well I would do [X]" which is just a projection of what use case that the comment author happened to be thinking of - i.e. the part where **it depends**.

Comment: @BlackJack See above comment.

Comment: Additionally, the question was about whether the last case should have a _condition_ on it; not what the implemented body of the last case should be. Throwing exceptions in the last case is fine (I frequently use it too) but it doesn't help answer the question whether the last case (regardless of it being a "normal logic" or "throw exception" implementation) should carry a condition on it or not.

Answer (score 57):

Even Case 1 can have unexpected behaviour. The value of n that worries me is [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

```py
n = float('nan')
if n == 0:
    doThis()  # Not triggered
elif n < 0:
    doThat()  # Not triggered
elif n > 0:
    doSomethingElse()  # Not triggered
```

This would be a problem if the rest of the program assumes that one of these has been run. To avoid this you could raise an exception from a final else:

```py
if n == 0:
    doThis()
elif n < 0:
    doThat()
elif n > 0:
    doSomethingElse()
else:
    raise Exception
```

Comment: This. Either use an `else` for a catch-all, or use `else` for the last case _with an `assert`_. In either case, double-check that you did account for all situations.

Comment: For the fast reader (skimming over longer code) using else will make clear "one of these cases will be executed for sure". Using only if/else-if always implies "this may be optional - there may be cases which skip over this block". (and the compiler may see it the same way, e.g. warning about an uninitialized variable, if you have no else case)

Comment: I think one thing to note is that although small things like this might feel more right to one person or another and are perfectly fine to discuss when writing your own code - don't let it impede team PRs because it's too small to start a debate over.  I've gotten more and more frustrated over the years at different employers where these conversations take up way too much time when instead our team could be moving forward.

Comment: @aaaaaa: I'm not a fan of letting bugs in in the name of "friendliness" or "productivity". Instead, I'd recommend having the discussion _once_, with the team, coming to an agreement, and making it a review guideline with a link to the summary of the discussion. Anybody who wishes to challenge the discussion in the future is welcome to, but should first acquaint themselves with the summary and ensure their arguments are genuinely new.

Comment: Doing relational logic on floats is not for the feint of heart.

Comment: I was tempted to agree with OP on their choice of including `coding-style` as a tag on the question.  This answer makes me want to reassess all my own "styles" to see what incorrectness I've been hiding

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Which assert would you write?

Comment: @EricDuminil: If you replace `elif n > 0:` by `else:`, I'd write `assert(n > 0)`, since that's the assumption being made.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The assumption at that point is `n == 0 or n < 0 or n > 0`.  But I don't see a point in repeating the conditions as this is repeated code which must be kept in sync.  I would use `assert False, f"unexpected value {n}"`.

Comment: @BlackJack: You're misunderstanding my comment. I am referring to replacing the last `elif` by an `else` + `assert`, not about adding an `else` that should never be taken. In the latter case (never be taken), then no condition need be checked, it's an unconditional throw. Just `raise` (or use `assert False` if you so wish).

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of `n > 0` vs `n < 0` vs `n == 0`, I think it's best to write the `==` case last and use `else` for it, but with a comment, like this:

```
if n > 0:
    ...
elif n < 0:
    ...
else: # n == 0
    ...
```

It is easier for a human reader to see at a glance that the comment is true if the cases are listed in this order, than if `n == 0` is one of the first two cases.

Your concerns about supplying an argument of the wrong type to this function would be better addressed with type annotations.

Comment: I try to avoid arguments that explain "what". In this case, if I change the first condition to `n > 1` and forget to edit the comment (it may be further down if the body of the if is longer) then the comment will be wrong. - I try to use comments only when I explain **why** not **what**

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but in this case you _must_ edit two places anyway, so a third place is not much worse. And I think of this particular comment as a "why" comment, because it explains why you don't need `elif` here.

Comment: I won't need to edit in two places, if the else-behavior suits my needs. Example: before `n>0` was 'good' `n<0` was 'bad' and everything in between is 'average'. If I increase the limit for 'good' to `n>1` I don't need to edit anything else, but the comment is now out of date and will confuse the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Your own primary objection to your version 2 (with the unconditional `else`) seems to be that it acts wrongly when the type of the variable is not integer.

I'd argue that your first version is wrong as well. If `n` is not an integer, it will not enter any of the three cases and do nothing. This would not be the expected behaviour - I would want to have some indication that something went very wrong. Just silently swallowing the error condition by doing nothing is the same (in my opinion) than erroneously doing something. Both can be incredibly frustrating to debug, and can cause untold harm and suffering to your data.

So. If your data *can* be wrong in some ways (be it type, domain, etc.) then you should do error checking before using the data. This is obviously mandatory when using data that comes from the outside.

For a method like this, modern Python does offer [type checking of arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) (arguably only in IDEs etc, not enforced).

To answer your original question; my personal preference is the style with a dangling unconditional `else`. And if I'm in doubt, then that case will be pure error handling (i.e., raising an exception if the language supports it).

I.e.:

```
if (someChecksFailed(n)):
  raise ValueError(f("Invalid argument: {n}")

if a(n):
  doA()
elif b(n):
  doB()
else:
  raise ValueError(f"Huh? Unexpected argument: {n}")
```

Or, if I'm very sure that nothing can really go wrong after my checks:

```
if (someChecksFailed(n)):
  raise ValueError(f("Invalid argument: {n}")

if a(n):
  doA()
elif b(n):
  doB()
else:
   doC()
```

Finally, if "doing nothing" is a perfectly valid possibility, you can make it explicit:

```
if (someChecksFailed(n)):
  raise ValueError(f("Invalid argument: {n}")

if a(n):
  doA()
elif b(n):
  doB()
else:
   None
```

Performance differences should be so irrelevant here that I would never take them into consideration at this point - if and when it turns out that that spot *is* for some reason performance sensitive then it's time to optimize, but this kind of construct should first and foremost be correct and easy to maintain.

Comment: "modern Python does offer type checking of arguments" - note that the `typing` module just provides type hints. It's up to your IDE or third-party tools to actually do type checking. And no runtime type checking is done.

Comment: Thanks @NotThatGuy, I have modified my statement.

Comment: If you want to explicitly do nothing, [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is better than `None`, since the latter looks like you're using the value for something.

Comment: "If n is not an integer, it will not enter any of the three cases and do nothing." Hence the reason I added this: "Pass in a non-integer object (one that implements `__lt__` and `__eq__`)".

Comment: @AnoE There are many types besides `int` that could end up in a branch, so ”type checking” might be unnecessary restricting. `float`, `decimal.Decimal`, `fractions.Fraction`, just to mention a few from the standard library.  And countless types defined in third party modules.  On the other hand if you pass in a `str` value, this won't just do nothing silently but fail with a `TypeError` at the `<` comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is: You are sure there are the three cases n>0, n=0 and n<0, but people who are sure they are right are often wrong. And you would want to express that.

Swift has a switch statement where the compiler requires a guarantee that every case is handled. In your case, you write your three cases. The compiler checks that everything is covered. If not then you must add another case handling the missing values, or a “default” statement. If everything is covered, “default” is not allowed. If the compiler cannot check it, it’s not allowed.

So you would write down your three cases, and everything is clear. Two cases plus default means there *might* be cases that you missed. Three cases + default is not allowed.

(In another post: What if I change “n > 0” to “n > 1”? The compiler would figure out that not everything is covered and force you to fix it somehow. If you wrote two cases + default then the default would now unexpectedly include the “n = 1” case.

An easy fix in any language would be instead of a final else or else if have a statement “remaining n > 0” which implies an assert that everything is covered, with the compiler optimising things.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned python is dynamically typed, hence either ensure using numbers or use `elif n > 0:`.

(Could even apply some comparison three valued type. Like `signum`. Or an else exception.)

But you favor speed. The overhead may exists, may be optimized away (in python?), but is minor.

Better optimize by probable number frequency (most frequent first):

```
if n > 0:
    ...
elif n < 0:
    ...
elif n == 0:
    ...
```

For a larger number of cases, nest `if` statements.